# How to use Ctrl+mouse click in tmux?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, tmux, clipboard, paste

Due to the change in Tmux2.1,
I need to remap my mouse's middle click to tmux's paste:

```
bind -T root MouseDown2Pane run -b "tmux paste-buffer"
```

However, I also would like to enable using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
(or <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>) + middle click
to paste the system's clipboard.

This is what I have tried (failed) so far:

```
bind -T root M+MouseDown2Pane run -b "pbpaste | tmux load-buffer -; tmux paste-buffer"
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified from [here](https://github.com/chbatey/tmux-config/blob/129258a55d32c93bfb6af51cce216ac03505b8c9/.tmux.conf#L53) - I use `xclip` instead of `xsel` in the original:

```
bind -T root MouseDown2Pane run -b "xclip -o | tmux load-buffer - && tmux paste-buffer -s ' '"
```

This is working merrily for me in `tmux 2.5-rc2`

Comment: this is great, but it does not work properly with vim in normal mode

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tmux-2.6 command for pasting on middle-click, using 'xsel' command:

```
bind-key -n MouseDown2Pane run -b "xsel | tmux load-buffer - && tmux paste-buffer -s ' '"
```